# How do I optimize an ORDER condition to prevent filesort?

Tags: mysql, counter-cache

How do I avoid a filesort when I want to order a query by condition in MySQL?

```
ORDER BY (videos_count > 0) DESC, name
```

Would it be better to cache a `has_videos` boolean column as well as the count?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+filesort

Comment: Do you have a composite index on (video_count, name)? Not sure if MySQL is clever enough to use it (because of the function), but you'll need that in any case.

Comment: Yes, I have a composite index but I believe the static indexes don't help out when doing comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about partitioning the query into two, first the ones with at least one video, then (only if needed) the rest:

```
select *  from video_table  
where video_count > 0
order by name
```

And if you need to go beyond those:

```
select *  from video_table  
where video_count = 0
order by name
```

Comment: This works great with `video_count != 0` rather than `video_count > 0`. However, the two union calls require more rows and needs a table scan to pull everything together.

Comment: It would not call them as a UNION, but separately, and only the first one, and if needed the second one, joined in application code. And the number of rows should be the same at the worst (and less, if you only need to run the first query).

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, in order to avoid a filesort you generally need to hit an index - and in order to hit an index, you generally need to be sorting on bare column values (since indices are created for columns, generally).

Comment: It will give the ones with video_count>0 on top, but it will not sort by name within that group (it will sort by video_count first).

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit. In that case, yeah, you'd need to add another column if you want to sort by both things and still avoid a filesort.